# Alfresco custom subtypes for cm:folder not working

Tags: alfresco, models, alfresco-share

I tried to to create a new folder type, that inherits everything from cm:folder, so I created an xml file for myModel.xml under tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/models, and added the following content to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0      modelSchema.xsd" -->
<model name="my:custmodel" 
   xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<description>custom folder test</description>
<author>Max Mustermann</author>
<published>2015-11-24</published>
<version>1.0</version>
<imports>
  <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
  <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys"/>
</imports>

<namespaces>
  <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
  <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/rendition/1.0" prefix="rn"/>
  <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/exif/1.0" prefix="exif"/>
  <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/audio/1.0" prefix="audio"/>
  <namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/webdav/1.0" prefix="webdav"/>
  <namespace uri="http://www.example.com/model/content/1.0" prefix="my" />
</namespaces>

<types>
<type name="my:folder1">
    <title>folder1</title>
    <parent>cm:folder</parent>
    <archive>true</archive>
 </type>
 <type name="my:folder2">
    <title>folder2</title>
    <parent>cm:folder</parent>
    <archive>true</archive>
 </type>
 </types>
```

then I added the following line to tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/custom-model-context.xml

```
<value>alfresco/extension/models/myModel.xml</value>
```

and finally in tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml:

```
<type name="cm:folder">
            <subtype name="my:folder1" />
            <subtype name="my:folder2" />
</type>
```

Now the under details->change Typ, my subtypes appear, but when I try to apply them I get "cannot change type of document ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model file name in context file is mentioned as

```
<value>alfresco/extension/models/custModel.xml</value>
```

in your description you are saying name as **"myModel.xml"**  is that a typo? Otherwise your file entries looks okey. Hope you are placing those entries properly.

This entry

```
<namespace uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
```

should be part of `<imports>` tag not `<namespaces>`

Something like this

```
 <imports>
      <!-- Import Alfresco Dictionary Definitions -->
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
      <!-- Import Alfresco Content Domain Model Definitions -->
      <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
   </imports>
```

Comment: I changed the real modelname for this stackoverflow post, and did make that mistake while tipping, also the xml header got lost, I corrected it now...

Comment: Many thanks! , I'am just new at alfresco, but with your help I got it work